# Open workbook in read-write and save when closing

Tags: excel, vba

so i have this code i got but it is opening all my workbooks in the directory as read only. I need to save it after it has runt the macro then close it... I believe this is the line I am suppose to change but I dont know which part of it

```
oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile, 0, True, , , , True, , , , False, , False)
```

Below is all the code

```
Dim oFSO
Dim oShell, oExcel, oFile, oSheet
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb2 = oExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\kp.AD\AppData\Roaming      \Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\CoventryStoplossMacroBook.xlsb") 'Specify foldername     here


oExcel.DisplayAlerts = True


For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\kpacheco.AD\Desktop\MSO_PR    \macro_test").Files
  If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "xls" Then
With oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile, 0, True, , , , True, , , , False, , False)


  'calling macro for MSO Eligibility reports
     oExcel.Run wb2.Name & "!MSOElig2"

 'I think im suppose to change the below to true but since it is read only    'it asks me to save a copy
     .Close False, , False
    End With
  End If



Next


wb2.Save

wb2.Close


oExcel.Quit
oShell.Popup "Conversion complete", 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReadOnly` property is flagged to `True` at the third position.
It should rather be `False` in order to open in read-write:

```
oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile, 0, False, , , , True, , , , False, , False)
```

Find more about the `Workbooks.Open()` method on the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx).

To save your workbook, you can use the `Save` and the `Close` methods separately; instead of:

```
.Close False, , False
```

to make it clearer I would use:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False '<-- if you don't want the alert
wb2.Save 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True '<-- set it back
wb2.Close
```

Comment: where should i add on here to save the workbook before closing so i dont have to do it in the macro?